# Initiate many variables with filler values in Python, pythonically

Tags: python, list, initialization, pep8

As I work on some code that handles inconsistent data, I want it to put certain values into variables when those values are available in the data, but if the values are not supplied, then I want to put filler values in the variables. I have tried a couple ways to do this, but neither seems pythonic.

```
name = ''
maxVal = '0'
minVal = '0'
...
```

or

```
[name, maxVal, minVal, ...] = ['', '0', '0', ...]
```

I tried

```
for var in [name, ...]:
    var = ''
```

and likewise for the `'0'` values, but the variables in the list need to be initialized first.

Is there a nice, succinct, pythonic way to initialize a good many variables so that they all hold filler values?

Comment: You can write `name, maxVal, minVal, ... = '', '0', '0', ...`. But the first way seems the most obvious.

Comment: the first way *is pythonic*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I agree that defining the variables one by one is not a blatant offense against PEP 8, but given that they all have the same, simple value, I find it hard to believe that that's *the* most pythonic path to take.

Comment: @Post169 why? That is idiomatic, clean, pythonic code that respects all the aspects of the Zen of Python. Pythonic doesn't mean "use tricks to put things onto a single line".

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Because if you have many variables that serve similar purposes and have the same value, it is more simple and beautiful to group them and then assign them that value all at once, which communicates to the reader that they belong together and have the same value for the same reason, than to give that value to them one-by-one and leave it ambiguous whether they have anything to do with each other. There certainly are cases that don't fit this description where what I want to do would be unpythonic, but I think in my case it is pythonic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While what this question is asking for is not pythonic in all cases that it could be used in, it is arguably pythonic to make modification of the second way shorter if the variables are associated with each other in their use and not only in the value that they hold. (If they're not used together or for similar purposes, the first way is the most pythonic way.)

In which case, you can do something along the lines of

```
name, ... = ('',)*n
maxVal, minVal, ... = ('0',)*m
```

with n and m being the number of variables in each sequence, and the commas serving to indicate a tuple.

(I got this from a coworker whom StackOverflow has missed out on.)